# Best development technologies to use to connect to exchange server, discover DAGs, creating mailbox data bases etc... (preferably in C#. .net)

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am new to Development with Exchange server. I am trying to do things like conencting to exchange server, discovering and creating Database Availablity Groups (DAG), discovering and creating mail box databses within a DAG etc... programmatically.

I see there are few PowerShell cmdlets to do the above things. I am wondering what is the best development technology to use for above things? Can i use EWS Manamgement API?

the technology should be compatible with Exchange Server 2010 and 2013 and preferably .net (C# - please note that i am trying to manage remote exchange servers)

regards,

Dreamer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option to manage exchange server is wrapping exchange management shell cmdlets in c# and invoking them.

Please see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/155504b3-ffe3-4bdf-887a-1e61842a8697 for more details.

thank you,
Dreamer